# How to use a percentual delta in Keras EarlyStopping?

Tags: python, keras

The [documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) says this should be an absolute minimum change:

> min_delta: minimum change in the monitored quantity to qualify as an improvement, i.e. an absolute change of less than min_delta, will count as no improvement.

Is there another method capable of using a percentage change value?

Comment: You need to implement your own callback in this case. Copy the code from the `EarlyStopping` callback and adapt it.